# TSQL - Calculating datediff in a query and setting a value?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datediff

Using SQL Server 2008, I want to calculate the timespan, in seconds, that has occurred between two times.

The start date, is the timestamp of the last occurance of where a specific ID exists (if the filter is true), get the time from that timestamp record, and do a DATEDIFF() against the current processing time and return a value, @LastEventTimespan, in seconds.

```
DECLARE @CurrentProcessTime DATETIME
DECLARE @LastEventTimespan DATETIME
SET @CurrentProcessTime = GetDate()

-- find the timespan since the last session event
-- DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

SELECT MAX(PageVisitEventID) AS LastPageVisitEventID, @LastEventTimespan = DATEDIFF(second , DateAdded , @CurrentProcessTime )
FROM PageVisitEvents
WHERE UserID = @UserID
GROUP BY LastPageVisitEventID
```

I figured I could get the MAX ID of the filter and process accordingly but am unable to set the @LastEventTimespan, however trying to assign a value when doing data-retrieval is a no-no.

How can I get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is just wrong I'm sorry. What do you plan to do with @LastEventTimespan? Given you'll have multiple rows because of the GROUP BY, it's also meaningless because it could be any of the rows as well as not allowed. However, you'd need to GROUP BY on it if you want it calculate it per row. And you don't GROUP BY on your MAXed column anyway so this makes things worse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want something like this.

```
DECLARE @LastEventTimespan INT

SELECT TOP 1 @LastEventTimespan = DATEDIFF(SECOND, DateAdded, GETDATE())
FROM PageVisitEvents  
WHERE UserID = @UserID
ORDER BY PageVisitEventID DESC
```

This will calculate the difference in seconds between DateAdded for the highest value of PageVisitEventID for a given user and the current DateTime. I changed the data type of `@LastEventTimespan` to `INT` because it probably makes more sense when dealing with seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the SELECT statement with this one:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    @LastEventTimespan = DATEDIFF(second , DateAdded , @CurrentProcessTime )
FROM PageVisitEvents
WHERE UserID = @UserID
ORDER BY PageVisitEventID desc
```

I've done such queries many times and never had problems.

Comment: @gbn : you're right, I remove the retrieval of the Id field. thanks for the info.